# Pass $(this) into setTimeout function in mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a div of information on a bar graph if the user hovers over the bar for a second. The answers on this site have gotten me to this point

```
var timer;
$(".session_hover").on({
     'mouseover': function () {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
              $(this).children('.session_info').css({'top':175,'right':20}).fadeIn('fast');
          }, 1000);
     },
     'mouseout' : function () {
          clearTimeout(timer);
     }
});
```

The above code works when I replace `$(this)` with `$(".session_hover")` but then, of course it triggers all the other `$(".session_hover")` on the page.

How can I pass `$(this)` into my `setTimeout` function so that it only applies to the child element of the div I am hovering over?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the 'that = this' trend really anoys me, why can't it be given the name of what it is !! : )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try creating a closure around a variable to capture `$(this)`, and then use it in your function:

```
 'mouseover': function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
          $this.children('.session_info').css({'top':175,'right':20}).fadeIn('fast');
      }, 1000);
 },
```

Note that in modern browsers, you can also provide `this` as a parameter to `setTimeout`, like this:

```
 'mouseover': function () {
      timer = setTimeout(function (t) {
          $(t).children('.session_info').css({'top':175,'right':20}).fadeIn('fast');
      }, 1000, this);
 },
```

However, if you want this to work in IE < 9, you need to use one of the polyfill techniques described in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Comment: I like the use of `closure` and `$this`

Comment: +1 for not only using the variable name `$this` but mentioning the new way for `setTimeout`

Comment: Never knew you could pass context to setTimeout like that. Great feature!

Comment: just realised what you mean there Brandon, yes nice!

Answer (score 2):

You need to hold a reference to `this` outside the setTimeout.

```
var timer;
$(".session_hover").on({
     'mouseover': function () {
          var ctx = this;
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
              $(ctx).children('.session_info').css({'top':175,'right':20}).fadeIn('fast');
          }, 1000);
     },
     'mouseout' : function () {
          clearTimeout(timer);
     }
});
```

Another alternative is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which is part of ECMAScript 5 (IE9+).

```
var timer;
$(".session_hover").on({
     'mouseover': function () {
          timer = setTimeout((function () {
              $(this).children('.session_info').css({'top':175,'right':20}).fadeIn('fast');
          }).bind(this), 1000);
     },
     'mouseout' : function () {
          clearTimeout(timer);
     }
});
```

[Here's a demo using Bind](http://jsfiddle.net/9UKns/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var timer;
$(".session_hover").on({
     var self = this;
     'mouseover': function () {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
              $(self).children('.session_info').css({'top':175,'right':20}).fadeIn('fast');
          }, 1000);
     },
     'mouseout' : function () {
          clearTimeout(timer);
     }
});
```